# Could not call install_name_tool

Tags: python, xcode, virtualenv

Trying to use virutalenv version 1.6.4 (the latest at writing this post) on 10.7, Lion with yes Xcode 4 installed from mac app store, yet i'm getting the below error message:

```
New python executable in SUPENV/bin/python
Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory while executing command install_name_tool -change /System/Library/Fram.../Versions/2.7/Python @executable_path/../.Python SUPENV/bin/python
Could not call install_name_tool -- you must have Apple's development tools installed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 8, in <module>
load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.6.4', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 810, in main
never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 901, in create_environment
site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1166, in install_python
py_executable])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 843, in call_subprocess
cwd=cwd, env=env)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1202, in _execute_child
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any hints on how to solve this problem... I guess the first would be to check if install_name_tool is present on my system, and then force virtualenv to use it...

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you actually install Xcode 4? Downloading it from the App Store only downloads the installer for it.  Then you need to run the installer;  you should find the installer downloaded to `/Applications`.  After you run it, you should find `install_name_tool` here:

```
$ which install_name_tool
/usr/bin/install_name_tool
```

Comment: You're not the first or the last!  It *is* a bit surprising that it doesn't install itself.

Answer (score 10):

You need to both install XCode, run it, and select the optional "command line tools" package and then install those.  In more detail:

- Download XCode from the App Store
- Run the downloaded XCode binary from Applications or Launchpad
- Select XCode->Preferences, then choose the "Downloads" tab
- Click on the "Command Line Tools" selection and install those

Answer (score 0):

With newer versions of virtualenv (at least from 1.8.4 on) it is no longer necessary to install the "Command Line Tools" package from Xcode.